# Wasserstein distance for two normal cdfs

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory, statistics, probability-distributions

Just came to know about a fact that the **Wasserstein distance** between two cumulative distribution functions, $F_1$ and $F_2$, can be expressed as: $$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} |F_1 (x)-F_2(x)| dx$$.

Is it possible to compute this distance in case $F_1$ and $F_2$ are two normal distributions, with constant variance $1$ and means $\mu_1 \neq \mu_2$ by hand?

I have no clue how to work with the absolute value along with the integral which does not seem to have a closed form!

Comment: if $\mu_2 >\mu_1$, you always have $F_2 \le F_1$ (one is a shifted version of the other) ; therefore you can drop the absolute value !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Suppose that $\mu_2 > \mu_1$.

The graph of density of $N(\mu_1, 1)$ lies to the left of the graph of density of $N(\mu_2, 1)$. As it was already mentioned by Jean Marie, it follows that $F_1 > F_2$.

It's known that if $\xi$ has distribution function $F(x)$ then $\mathbf{E}\xi = \int_{-\infty}^{0} (- F(x))dx + \int_{0}^{\infty} (1  - F(x))dx$.

Suppose that $\xi_i \sim N(\mu_i, 1)$. We have
$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} |F_1(x) - F_2(x)|dx = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} (F_1(x) - F_2(x))dx =$$
$$= \int_{-\infty}^{0} (- F_2(x))dx -  \int_{-\infty}^{0} (- F_1(x))dx + \int_{0}^{\infty} (F_1(x) - F_2(x))dx =$$
$$= \int_{-\infty}^{0} (- F_2(x))dx -  \int_{-\infty}^{0} (- F_1(x))dx + \int_{0}^{\infty} ((1  - F_2(x)) - (1-F_1(x)))dx =$$
$$=\int_{-\infty}^{0} (- F_2(x))dx + \int_{0}^{\infty} (1  - F_2(x))dx  -$$
$$ -  \bigg( \int_{-\infty}^{0} (- F_1(x))dx + \int_{0}^{\infty} (1  - F_1(x))dx 
 \bigg)= $$
$$= \mathbf{E}\xi_2 - \mathbf{E}\xi_1 = \mu_2 - \mu_1.$$
It follows that the answer is $|\mu_2 - \mu_1|.$